# SharePoint 2019 ON PREMISE - Change font size for lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, css, sharepoint-on-prem

I am having trouble in changing font sizes for lists in SP on-premise.

I have some custom css where I have changed font sizes for most areas of our sites - I am stuck with adjusting the size of fonts for lists.

I know I am looking to adjust the ms-fontSize in the additionalRowClass but I don't know where to apply it. Any help appreciated.

It is a modern communication site.

Answer (score 0):

What type of template is that , either Classic site or Modern site?
If it is Classic site you can add it into your master page else If it is modern site you need to create Application Extension customizer(SPFx) and add that app to your site collection

Comment: It's a modern site.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply custom code via the [SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) on modern pages in SharePoint Server 2019.

See the reference here for a tutorial: [Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions.](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

Also see the link here for what customization is supported for the time being: [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages).

Please note that customizing master pages for modern experience is not supported, so you will not be able to apply the CSS code once and for all.